# Is this possible with an alert in jquery and/or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, alert, droppable

for a school project I'm making a jigsaw out of jquery and javascript. 
I'm using jquery and jquery impromptu jquery (custom alert messages).

now the problem is, I want the site to give an alert if all four pieces are positioned correctly. Is this possible? 
It currently gives a message for every correctly positioned piece.

jquery code:

```
 $(function() {
    $( ".draggable_l_t" ).draggable({ snap: ".droppable_l_t, .droppable_r_t, .droppable_l_b, .droppable_r_b", snapMode: "inner" });
    $( ".draggable_r_t" ).draggable({ snap: ".droppable_l_t, .droppable_r_t, .droppable_l_b, .droppable_r_b", snapMode: "inner" });
    $( ".draggable_l_b" ).draggable({ snap: ".droppable_l_t, .droppable_r_t, .droppable_l_b, .droppable_r_b", snapMode: "inner" });
    $( ".draggable_r_b" ).draggable({ snap: ".droppable_l_t, .droppable_r_t, .droppable_l_b, .droppable_r_b", snapMode: "inner" });

    $( ".droppable_l_t" ).droppable({
        accept: ".draggable_l_t",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( this )
                    $.prompt('Goed geplaatst.',{ buttons: { Ok: true, Cancel: false }, focus: 1 });
        }
    });

    $( ".droppable_r_t" ).droppable({
        accept: ".draggable_r_t",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( this )

                    $.prompt('Goed geplaatst.',{ buttons: { Ok: true, Cancel: false }, focus: 1 });
        }
    });

    $( ".droppable_l_b" ).droppable({
        accept: ".draggable_l_b",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( this )
                    $.prompt('Goed geplaatst.',{ buttons: { Ok: true, Cancel: false }, focus: 1 });
        }
    });
    $( ".droppable_r_b" ).droppable({
        accept: ".draggable_r_b",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( this )
                    $.prompt('Goed geplaatst.',{ buttons: { Ok: true, Cancel: false }, focus: 1 });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

the whole site is reachable [here](http://friso.webatu.com/Site/droppablejquery.htm). and the other files are [here](http://friso.webatu.com/Site/).

could you help me with this problem? thanks in advance, Friso

Comment: why not keep a global variable which increments whenever a successful piece is place. on every success, increment it and see if it equals 4 ?

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do this with jQuery 1.5 `Deferred()` objects.

Create one such object for each piece:

```
var def = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
   def[i] = $.Deferred();
}
```

Then when each piece is finished, `resolve` the appropriate deferred object:

```
def[n].resolve();
```

Then at the end of your code, register a callback that's only invoked when they're all done:

```
$.when.apply($, def).done(function() {
    // this will be called only when all the promises are resolved
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, but I have some problems with putting your code in my code. I don't have much experience with jquery. Could you tell me where to put the code specifically? What should I do with the current alert's (prompt)?

Comment: put the first block right at the top, the `resolve` inside each `drop` callback function, and the `when` block right at the end.